# Plot3D modifies the shape of a plot

Tags: plotting

I have a little problem with the Plot3D function. Depending on how I define my variables, the shape of the plot is not exactly the same.

The first way I use is for instance:

Plot3D[If[Sin[x*y*z] > 1/2, Sin[x*y*z], 0] /. z -> 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]

[image]

You can see that the graph is continued which should not be the case.

And the second is:

z = 1;
Plot3D[If[Sin[x*y*z] > 1/2, Sin[x*y*z], 0], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]

[image]

Here the graph is not continued but now I have defined a global z.

I prefer using the first way because in this case z is only defined for the plot, yet I prefer the shape of the second way. How could I have a discontinued graph but without defining a global z ?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the first argument with `Evaluate`:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[If[Sin[x y z] > 1/2, Sin[x y z], 0] /. z -> 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the option [`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html):

```
Plot3D[If[Sin[x y z] > 1/2, Sin[x y z], 0] /. z -> 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   Exclusions -> {Sin[x y ] == 1/2}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thank you, it is working fine with Evaluate !

Comment: @Raphaël, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.